# Time Displaying Incorrectly on InfoPath Form and Not Displaying Current User

Tags: infopath, date-time, modified

I have 2 controls below. The top Text box is labeled **CommentsTemp** while the bottom TextBox is called **Comments**. How it works is, when a user enters anything in CommentsTemp, that it would be stored in the Comments. As long as users keep adding comments and saving, it will keep storing new comments without deleting the old:

[image]

The rule displayed below is for my Submit button. Based on the rule I’m displaying the Date & Time (**now()**), the Display Name (**Modified By**), CommentsTemp (**explained above**), and Comments (**explained above**):

[image]

Below is detailed look at DisplayName in the rule above. I then publish the form to my List:

[image]

Below, I had a user (let’s call him **Ed Burg**) test with me and add a new item and add some comments. It all works as expected. *It display the time, the user who added the comment and whatever it is the user typed in*. 
In the far right it displays the Modified By column and displays Ed Burg. Great!

[image]

However, I (**M Rob**) went to the same item above and attempt to edit the item by adding a comment but it still displays the user as **Ed Burg**. *BUT* it displays my user **M Rob** in the **Modified By** column on the far right:

[image]

It seems as when I attempt to Edit and Save the item it is still registering as the current user in the column Modified By.

The desired is to show the username of whoever Modified the item. Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Also, for displaying the time in the second screenshot, I have the formula to display “now()”.

The **issue** is that it is displaying for me **2 hours behind** and for another user is displaying **3 hours behind** when tested. I also tested by using **Modified** instead of **now()** and the same issue.

How can I display the correct time regardless of what time zone the user is?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that this feature can be achieved using the multiple line of text field and enable 'Append Text to Existing Text' (Just make sure versioning is turned on) as the screen shot here shows:
[image]

once you do that you can keep track of all the comments with time stamp like that:

[image]

you can use that in your infoPath and you don't need to do any coding :)

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe I missed that. I tested your suggestion but the only thing I think my client will not like is that the Multi line column will display "View Entries". Is there a way around that? Also, I wanted to confirm from you in regards to your time stamp. Are those times accurate or are they server times? Because mine is displaying 2 hours behind but can't seem to navigate to correct setting to fix. Please advise. Thanks